# Type safe MongoDB find wrapper

Tags: typescript, mongodb, typescript-generics

I'm working on a typescript project in which we use MongoDB. I'm trying to create a generic, type safe, wrapper for all my database queries. In this wrapper I use conditional types to determine the collection Schema which I got working but I'm failing to define a projection which narrows the scope of the filter and the result type from the function.

Love to get some input here.

**EDIT 22-12-2023: Solved it using a overload function type. Here's the code if anyone is facing the same issue :)**

```
import {Filter, MongoClient, WithId} from 'mongodb'

// Definition of data in collection 1
interface Alerts {
  message: string
  severity: number
}
// Definition of data in collection 2
interface Animals {
  type: string
  legs: number
}

// Determine the right definition for the collection
type CollectionType<T> = T extends {collectionName: 'alerts'} ? Alerts : T extends {collectionName: 'animals'} ? Animals : never
// Saved data has an _id
type TSchema<T> = WithId<CollectionType<T>>
// Definition for the projection object
type Projection<T> = {[Property in keyof TSchema<T>]?: 0 | 1}
// Projection fields
type Fields<T> = (keyof TSchema<T>)[]

interface GetWithoutProjection<T> {
  collectionName: 'alerts' | 'animals'
  filter: Filter<TSchema<T>>
}
interface GetWithProjection<T> extends GetWithoutProjection<T> {
  project: Fields<T>
}
type GetParams<T> = GetWithProjection<T> | GetWithoutProjection<T>

type GetOneFunction = {
  <T extends GetWithProjection<T>>(params: T): Promise<Pick<TSchema<T>, T['project'][0]>>
  <T extends GetWithoutProjection<T>>(params: T): Promise<TSchema<T>>
}

const getOne: GetOneFunction = async <T extends GetParams<T>>(params: T) => {
  const {filter, collectionName} = params

  const client = await MongoClient.connect('connection-string')
  const collection = client.db('db-name').collection<TSchema<T>>(collectionName)

  const projection: Projection<T> = {}
  if ('project' in params) {
    projection._id = 0
    params.project.forEach(p => {
      projection[p] = 1
    })
  }

  const result = await collection.findOne(filter, {projection})
  if (!result) throw new Error(`No document found for ${JSON.stringify(filter)} in ${collectionName}`)
  return result
}

export const test = async () => {
  // WithId<Alerts>
  const alerts1 = await getOne({collectionName: 'alerts', filter: {}})
  console.log(alerts1.severity)
  // WithId<Animals>
  const animal1 = await getOne({collectionName: 'animals', filter: {}})
  console.log(animal1.type)

  // Pick<WithId<Alerts, '_id' | 'message'>
  const alerts2 = await getOne({collectionName: 'alerts', project: ['_id', 'message'], filter: {}})
  console.log(alerts2.severity)
  // Property 'severity' does not exist on type 'Pick<TSchema<{ collectionName: "alerts"; project: ("_id" | "message")[]; filter: {}; }>, "_id" | "message">'.

  // Pick<WithId<Animals, '_id' | 'legs'>
  const animal2 = await getOne({collectionName: 'animals', project: ['_id', 'legs'], filter: {}})
  console.log(animal2.type)
  // Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Pick<TSchema<{ collectionName: "animals"; project: ("_id" | "legs")[]; filter: {}; }>, "_id" | "legs">'
}
```

Comment: Not an answer directly, but instead of writing all the types manually you could use a tool like [prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) to generate the typescript types automatically and do your querying. They also have support for MongoDB to my knowledge.

Comment: Or Mongoose, why reinvent the wheel?